# upload directly to s3 from laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, filesystems, homestead

I am using laravel 5.1 currently on homestead for developing locally. I am working on an established laravel source code. I changed the filesystem config to use S3. I am having an issue with making the code upload directly to s3, or upload to s3 at all. Here is the current code:

```
<?php
class ImageHandler {

public static function uploadImage($image, $folder, $filename = '', $type = 'upload'){
    return call_user_func ( Config::get('site.media_upload_function'), array('image' => $image, 'folder' => $folder, 'filename' => $filename, 'type' => $type) );
}

public static function getImage($image, $size = ''){
    $img = ''; // placeholder image

    $image_url = Config::get('site.uploads_dir') . 'images/';

    if($size == ''){
        $img = $image;
    } else {

        switch($size){
            case 'large':
                $img = str_replace('.' . pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), '-large.' . pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $image);
                break;
            case 'medium':
                $img = str_replace('.' . pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), '-medium.' . pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $image);
                break;
            case 'small':
                $img = str_replace('.' . pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), '-small.' . pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $image);
                break;
            default:
                $img = $image;
                break;
        }
    }

    return $image_url . $img;

}


public static function upload($args){

    // Lets get all these Arguments and assign them!
    $image = $args['image'];
    $folder = $args['folder'];
    $filename = $args['filename']; 
    $type = $args['type'];

    // Hey if the folder we want to put them in is images. Let's give them a month and year folder
    if($folder == 'images'){
        $month_year = date('FY').'/';
    } else {
        $month_year = '';
    }

    // Check it out! This is the upload folder
    $upload_folder = 'content/uploads/' . $folder . '/'.$month_year;


    if ( @getimagesize($image) ){

        // if the folder doesn't exist then create it.
        if (!file_exists($upload_folder)) {
            mkdir($upload_folder, 0777, true);
        }

        if($type =='upload'){

            $filename =  $image->getClientOriginalName();

            // if the file exists give it a unique name
            while (file_exists($upload_folder.$filename)) {
                $filename =  uniqid() . '-' . $filename;
            }


            $uploadSuccess = $image->move($upload_folder, $filename);

            if(strpos($filename, '.gif') > 0){
                $new_filename = str_replace('.gif', '-animation.gif', $filename);
                copy($upload_folder . $filename, $upload_folder . $new_filename);
            }

        } else if($type = 'url'){

            $file = file_get_contents($image);

            if(strpos($image, '.gif') > 0){
                $extension = '-animation.gif';
            } else {
                $extension = '.jpg';
            }


            $filename = $filename . $extension;

            if (file_exists($upload_folder.$filename)) {
                $filename =  uniqid() . '-' . $filename . $extension;
            }

            if(strpos($image, '.gif') > 0){
                file_put_contents($upload_folder.$filename, $file);
                $filename = str_replace('-animation.gif', '.gif', $filename);
            }

            file_put_contents($upload_folder.$filename, $file);

        }


        $settings = Setting::first();

        $img = Image::make($upload_folder . $filename);

        if($folder == 'images'){
            $img->resize(1280, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });

            Image::make($upload_folder . $filename)->resize(960, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($upload_folder . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '-large.' . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            Image::make($upload_folder . $filename)->resize(640, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($upload_folder . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '-medium.' . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            Image::make($upload_folder . $filename)->resize(320, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($upload_folder . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '-small.' . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        } else if($folder == 'avatars'){
            $img->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
        }

        $img->save($upload_folder . $filename);

        return $month_year . $filename;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How would I edit this code in order to upload the files directly to my s3 bucket?

Comment: Would you please update your question with more detail of what goes wrong? any error or warning?

Comment: try foloowing this article for a step by step how to upload dircetly to s3 http://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2013/direct-upload-to-s3-with-a-little-help-from-jquery/

Comment: @Ali, nothing goes wrong with the code. The site saves upload to the local directory. I am trying to have the files upload to s3 with respect to my chosen filesystem.

Comment: @DanielKatzan I don't think that article would help because laravel 5 natively supports uploads to s3. I am looking for a way to implement that support on an already established code above.